# How to Combine Columns with the Same Heading in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a set of cost data for different pieces of unique equipment. Each piece of equipment is classified as a particular equipment class which I have pulled from an index match on the unique equipment number. I now have a set of ~9000 columns of cost data, each with a column header of one of the ~300 equipment classes.

What I want to do is to get the median, 25%, and 75% for the full data set for each of these equipment classes.

I either want to create a single long column of all the data for each equipment class, or have a way to calculate the Percentile() values for the data in all columns with the same heading.

I could filter the data for each equipment class one at a time and calculate the percentile values, but with 300 equipment classes it would take forever.

Example:

```
Class01 Class02 Class01 Class03 Class03
1          4        7      10      13
2          5        8      11      14
3          6        9      12      15
```

And I want the 25%, median and 75% for the distribution for Class01, Class02, and Class03

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm thinking a sumproduct could work for this, probably even a sumifs/countifs method. What have you tried so far?

Comment: So a sumif/countif method could work if I only wanted an average, but I really need all the values for the data sets for each equipment class because I am looking at quantile values.
I haven't made much progress because the data set is so large I really just don't know how to attack the problem.

Comment: You will get more response if you show at least some effort on your part. May need to use array formulas then. Would need to spend some time playing to give you specifics. Is VBA an option?

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Sorry I am new to posting on the site. I will try to better detail previous attempts to solve the problem in my next post.
Thank you for your help, CallumDA has solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I either want to create a single long column of all the data for each equipment class, or have a way to calculate the Percentile() values for the data in all columns with the same heading.

I'll just tell you how to change your data around. From there the percentiles/ quartiles will be straight forward.

Start with your data like this. Notice that I added a column on the left. It's easy to make, just type `Item1` and drag down (or double click the small square in the bottom right corner of the cell)
[image]

You then need to hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

- Select **multiple consolidated ranges** > next
- Next (create page ranges for me...)
- Select all of your data as the range, click add then finish

You will now get a pivot table that looks like this:
[image]

Click the grand-grand total (i.e. `120`) and that will create another pivot table like this:
[image]

*Et voila*...

Comment: This worked perfectly to at all my data into a single column with the data corresponding classes. Thank you. This was much more efficient than the method I was using which worked for small data sets.

Now that I have the data arranged in this way, Is there an easy way to calculate the percentile values for these classes?

What I was thinking was to use a list of the classes and a count of the number of entries for each with the percentile function and an offset for the sum of the number of entries going down the list. Would that work or is there a better way?

Comment: excel has a `PERCENTILE` function (actually a few variations of the `PERCENTILE` function if you have Excel 2013 or later). You can use that